# Cucumber steps as spring beans

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm using Spring, Cucumber and Junit in my project. The test runner is annotated with `@ContextConfiguration` so it creates a Spring context before running the suite.

I would like **Spring** to instantiate the **Step Definition** classes as Spring beans so I can inject my dependencies and use them in the steps. It can be done by declaring the class as `@Component`.

So far so good. The problem is that **Cucumber will instantiate the step definitions again** and will not use the beans already created by Spring with the dependencies injected.

Any ideas to make Cucumber use the Step definitions instantiated by Spring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use spring to autowire controller in cucumber test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564938/can-i-use-spring-to-autowire-controller-in-cucumber-test)

Answer (score 0):

Your runner class should be annotated with `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` rather that with `@ContextConfiguration`. Cucumber should then scan and instantiate your Spring context accordingly.